# Lisp nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth in python-mode 6.2.3, Emacs 25.2

Tags: python, package

I have this simple Python test program:

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([0, 1, 4, 9])

def gen_segments(x, y):
    for i in range(0, len(x)-1):
        yield (x[i], x[i+1]), (y[i], y[i+1])

lines = [list(zip(s, t)) for s, t in gen_segments(x, y)]
```

when I position the cursor at the end of the line starting with `yield` and press ENTER, Emacs gives me the following error:

> "Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’"

I am using Emacs version 25.2 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Here is a minimal setup to reproduce the problem:

```
$ emacs -Q -l init.el t.py
```

where `t.py` is the above python program, and `init.el` is:

```lisp
(setq debug-on-error t)
(setq package-load-list '((python-mode t)))
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

The Python mode that `package-initialize` above loads was 
installed with the Emacs package manager as `python-mode-20170307.457` in my `elpa` directory. If I comment out the line `(package-initialize)` above, it works fine (then Emacs uses the Python mode in `/opt/emacs-25.2/share/emacs/25.2/lisp/progmodes/python.el.gz` instead).

Comment: Maybe report this as a bug

Comment: I don't get why people keep reporting bugs on SE, it's not like it's going to make upstream aware of them...

Comment: Couldn't reproduce at a first try. Please report that at https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Added [bug-report](https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues/38)